# Core bluetooth in WatchKit in apple watch?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, watchkit, apple-watch

I want my watch app to be identified by my paired iPhone.I am using CoreBluetooth Framework to implement this. I am transmitting bluetooth signals from my watch app and trying to receive the signal in my iPhone app. I am using the same concept as apple has shown in its sample code (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927) , the only difference is that my transmitter is the watch app.

**Issue**
I am unable to detect watch app in my iPhone. I have made sure that all of my hardwares are configured properly and I am configuring the Core bluetooth delegate methods properly. I also suspect if this method will be feasible with iPhone and apple watch.

All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible because your **WatchKit app runs as an extension on your iPhone** and therefore all Core Bluetooth bluetooth signals are sent from the iPhone itself to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Access to Core Bluetooth on Apple Watch lets your apps bypass the phone and connect directly with the Bluetooth in Apple Watch. Access Core Bluetooth to connect directly with accessories. And with Apple Watch Series 3, your apps can take advantage of built-in cellular and altimeter capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, **since watchOS 6 it's possible** to use `CoreBluetooth` on watchOS.

Check for more informations this link ["Creating Independent watchOS Apps"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps.)

Be aware there are still some limitations using `CoreBluetooth` in watchOS for example:

- The minimum connection interval is 30ms instead of 15ms (for iOS devices).
- The Apple watch can only operate as a central device.
- The Apple watch can only be connected to two peripherals at one Time
- The peripheral gets disconnected when the app goes into the background.

Maybe this will change when watchOS 7 is out.